# how to show the deselected option from the dropdown list in the other available dropdown list of that row in a table - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have a html table which has input text fields and dropdown list's as columns.
I have two dropdown list columns which displays the same list of options.

I'm trying to remove the option selected in one dropdown and doesn't show 
in the other dropdown present in the same row which is working when i select a option from Select Product1 dropdown list.

**Issues I'm facing** is when user first select the option from `Select Product2` column dropdown list, it is not removing the option from `Select Product1` column list for that row.

**Another issue is**, if user selected one option in the dropdown list that option is removed in the other drop down list, if user changes the selected option from first dropdown list the removed element should be shown/available in the other dropdown list but it is not showing the first selected option as it has been already removed from the list.

Any inputs on this two issues would be helpful, i tried to find the solution but no luck.

[Sample Demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/mxv6IqzC3AL08WDGk6r9?p=preview)

Code:

```js
//populate dropdown with the valu`enter code here`e
function populateSelect() {
    var ids = [{"pid":"laptop","des":"laptop"},{"pid":"Mobile","des":"Mobile"},{"pid":"IPAD mini.","des":"IPAD mini."},
        {"pid":"toys","des":"toys"},{"pid":"electronics","des":"electronics"},{"pid":"desktop","des":"desktop"},{"pid":"ipad Air","des":"ipad Air"}]
    var productDropdown1 = $(".product1");
    var productDropdown2 = $(".product2");
    $.each(ids, function(index,value) {
        $("<option />").text(value.des).val(value.pid).appendTo(productDropdown1);
        $("<option />").text(value.des).val(value.pid).appendTo(productDropdown2);
    });

    $('select').change(function() {
        var $sel = $(this),
                val = $sel.val();
        $sel.parent().siblings().find('.product2 option[value=' + val + ']').remove()

    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    populateSelect();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     
    <table id="orderTable" border="1">

        <tr>
            <th>Or.ID</th>
            <th>Select Product1</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Select Product2</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="orderNum" value="" id="orderNum1"></td>
            <td>
                <select class="product1" id="prod1">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="description" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="product2" id="product2">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="orderNum" value="" id="orderNum2"></td>
            <td>
                <select class="product1" id="prod2">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="description" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="product2" >
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="orderNum" value="" id="orderNum3"></td>
            <td>
                <select class="product1" id="prod3">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="description" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="product2" >
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="orderNum" value="" id="orderNum4"></td>
            <td>
                <select class="product1" id="prod4">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="description" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="product2" >
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: As I mentioned in previous answer for this the first issue is quickly solved by using a common class for both selects. `<select class ="product product1">` then change jQuery selectors to `.product`

Comment: @charlietfl - I tried as you suggested http://plnkr.co/edit/vsRuqAn09V7VmDyVjz6k?p=preview . It is working only for first time, again if user deselects the option and selects other option , the newly selected option value is not removed from the second dropdown list and vice versa..

Comment: Right. That's where I suggested you clone and store a full set of options when page loads. Then you can filter the stored set to find what's missing and put it back

Answer (score 1):

Every option in dropdown must have unique ID. When you select option "house" from dropdown menu "menu1", then remove/hide same option(option with same ID) from "menu2".
Another way to do it is that every option has `onClick` that will call some function.
Example:

```
<option value="" onclick="hideOption("menu2-option1")" id="menu1-option1">Option 1</option>

<!-- JS CODE -->
function hideOption(hideOptionID)
{
    document.getElementById(hideOptionID).style.display = "none"; 
}
```

Comment: You can't hide `<option>` cross browser. Will not work in browsers like IE and Safari among others. Same for events. That onclick will not work. Then the idea of giving every option an id is a waste of time and effort when there are easier ways to target an element

Comment: @charlietfl He can use jQuery `.hide()` to hide an element. It Works for me.
That is second way.

Comment: And you tried that in IE? And Safari? This is a years old issue and there are many many posts on this site about it

Comment: @charlietfl Works on Edge and Chrome. Doesn't have other browsers.

Comment: What version IE? Might work in edge...for sure not IE 10 and probably not 11 either. Yes it works in some...chrome and fiefox for example

Comment: Sorry, I mean Edge(primary browser). Guess then Works for IE(older Brother)

Comment: No that is a bad guess and events definitely don't work in safari

Comment: I can't check your answers, your rep history don't show them. Never delete an answers due to downvotes: first, a rep gain for an up is 5 times more than the loss for a down. Delete only if you already think, it is unrepairable bad. Second, if you know that your answer is good, and it is still voted down, then help the voters to show from themselves, how unfair they are. ;-) Btw, typically they are balanced out in the long-term, the months will go and others will vote your answer up (if it is really good). The case is worser with downvoted questions.

Comment: I don't understand why You wrote that comment

Answer (score 0):

It is better to disable an option than remove it from the ui.
try to change

```
$('select').change(function() {
        var $sel = $(this),
                val = $sel.val();
        $sel.parent().siblings().find('.product2 option[value=' + val + ']').remove()

});
```

To

```
    $('select').change(function() {    
            var $sel = $(this),
            val = $sel.val();
            //$('select').not($sel).find('option').removeAttr('disabled');
 $sel.parent().siblings().not($sel).find('option').removeAttr('disabled');
        $sel.parent().siblings().find('select option[value=' + val + ']').attr('disabled',true);
        });
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/bahmgjs8/2/)**

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I tried your demo fiddle, it is working for the first time when user has selected the option, but again when user changes the selected option for the second time it is not disabling the corresponding option in the second dropdown list. And is it difficult to remove the option instead of disabling? Inputs would be really helpful. TIA.

Comment: as per the documentation .remove() means "Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM" so the removed option won't be available anywhere in the DOM in case you want to show in any chance. That is why i suggested disabling instead of remove().

Comment: ok got it, when user has selected the options in dropdown one it is disabling in second dropdown list but issue is when user fills the data in other rows and go back to the first/old rows he could able to select the disabled option too.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: when user has selected the options in dropdown one it is disabling in second dropdown list but issue is when user fills the data in other rows and go back to the first/old rows he could able to select the disabled option too.

Comment: Its working, i will check to remove the selected option from second dropdown list too. Can you please update the answer so that i can accept it..Thanks for your time and inputs. Appreciate it.